# Is there way put info buttons for each node in reactflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

I want to add info button side of each node component. is this possible?
example, on picture you can think yellow marks which are buttons I want.

here return part of js code:
'''

{" "}
{display && (
<ReactFlow style={{ position: "absolute", zIndex: 1 }} nodes={nodes} edges={edges} fitView onNodeMouseEnter={handleOpen} onNodeMouseLeave={handleClose} onEdgeMouseEnter={handleEdgeOpen} onEdgeMouseLeave={handleEdgeClose}>
<??Button??/>

```
            </ReactFlow>
        )}
      </div>
```

'''

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is possible!
You can achieve this by creating a custom node